# Python pandas dataframe conversion to unixtime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unix-timestamp

I would like to convert a date of the format  with yyyy=year, mm=month, dd=day, hh=hour, nn=minute in a unix timestamp.
I tried:

```
df_out['unixtime'] = datetime(df_out['yyyymmddhhmm'].dt.year.to_numpy(),df_out['yyyymmddhhmm'].dt.month.to_numpy(),df_out['yyyymmddhhmm'].dt.day.to_numpy(),df_out['yyyymmddhhmm'].dt.hour.to_numpy(),df_out['yyyymmddhhmm'].dt.minute.to_numpy()).timestamp()
```

but I got the error message:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: Please share a sample input of dataframe with expected output.

Comment: share with us the input please

Answer (score 1):

The [officially](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#from-timestamps-to-epoch) recommended way is to subtract the epoch and then to floor-divide by the “unit” (1 second):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'yyyymmddhhmm': pd.to_datetime(['20201108121314', '20201109121314'])})

df['unixtime'] = (df.yyyymmddhhmm - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
```

Result:

```
         yyyymmddhhmm    unixtime
0 2020-11-08 12:13:14  1604837594
1 2020-11-09 12:13:14  1604923994
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single column for the date using the pandas library

```
 df_out['date_format'] = pd.to_datetime(df_out['date_time_column'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

Then you can create new columns which will consist of year, month, date, hour info by

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df_out['date_format']).year 
pd.DatetimeIndex(df_out['date_format']).month 
pd.DatetimeIndex(df_out['date_format']).day 
pd.DatetimeIndex(df_out['date_format']).hour
```